# Map-filter CPS version in Scheme

Tags: filter, scheme, map-function, continuation-passing

I'm wondering, is there any implementation of map-filter in CPS version in Scheme?

example:

```
(map-filter square even? '(1 2 3 4)) -> '(4 16)
```

Comment: This question is very unclear, and it's also not clear how your example is related to CPS. Could you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can define `map-filter&` using `filter&` and `map&`:

```
(define (map-filter& proc& pred?& lst k)
  (filter& pred?&
           lst
           (lambda (new-lst)
             (map& proc& new-lst k))))
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer give two versions of the function the person described: not CPS versions of it.  I think the question is ambiguous but this is probably not the right answer: Sylwester's is.]

If what you want is what you've described (which I'm fairly sure is not CPS), then something like this works:

```
(define (map-filter mapper filterer lst)
  (map mapper (filter filterer lst)))
```

In Racket then this might be better as this:

```
(define (map-filter mapper filterer lst)
  (for/list ([e (in-list lst)]
             #:when (filterer e))
    (mapper e)))
```

which perhaps has a better chance of avoiding consing an intermediate list but smells nastier to me.

Comment: None of these are [CPS](http://matt.might.net/articles/cps-conversion/)

Comment: @Sylwester: I agree (or not in any CPS I'm familiar with).  I had assumed that the person was after a function with the signature they gave, but I think I'm wrong now: they knew how to write that function but wanted a CPS conversion of it.